# Proguard throwing customtabs warnings and failing build

Tags: android, android-proguard

I just added an activity with a viewpager containing fragments and glide operations to a project and proguard is going nuts. This is the list of warnings:

```
Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzfts: can't find superclass or interface android.support.customtabs.CustomTabsServiceConnection
Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzfts: can't find referenced class android.support.customtabs.CustomTabsClient
Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzfts: can't find referenced class android.support.customtabs.CustomTabsServiceConnection
Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzfts: can't find referenced class android.support.customtabs.CustomTabsServiceConnection
Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzfts: can't find referenced class android.support.customtabs.CustomTabsClient
Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzftt: can't find referenced class android.support.customtabs.CustomTabsClient
Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzoe: can't find referenced class android.support.customtabs.CustomTabsClient
Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzoe: can't find referenced class android.support.customtabs.CustomTabsSession
Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzoe: can't find referenced class android.support.customtabs.CustomTabsClient
Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzoe: can't find referenced class android.support.customtabs.CustomTabsClient
Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzoe: can't find referenced class android.support.customtabs.CustomTabsClient
Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzoe: can't find referenced class android.support.customtabs.CustomTabsSession
Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzoe: can't find referenced class android.support.customtabs.CustomTabsSession
Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzoe: can't find referenced class android.support.customtabs.CustomTabsClient
Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzoe: can't find referenced class android.support.customtabs.CustomTabsServiceConnection
Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzoe: can't find referenced class android.support.customtabs.CustomTabsClient
Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzwl: can't find referenced class android.support.customtabs.CustomTabsIntent
Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzwl: can't find referenced class android.support.customtabs.CustomTabsIntent$Builder
Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzwl: can't find referenced class android.support.customtabs.CustomTabsIntent
Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzwl: can't find referenced class android.support.customtabs.CustomTabsIntent$Builder
Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzwl: can't find referenced class android.support.customtabs.CustomTabsIntent$Builder
```

This is the state of my proguard rules file:

```
 #-libraryjars   libs/android-support-v4.jar
 -dontwarn android.support.**
 #-keep class android.support.v4.** { *; }
 #-keep interface android.support.v4.app.** { *; }
 #-keepattributes *Annotation*

-keep public class * implements com.bumptech.glide.module.GlideModule
-keep public class * extends com.bumptech.glide.module.AppGlideModule
-keep public enum com.bumptech.glide.load.ImageHeaderParser$** {
  **[] $VALUES;
  public *;
}

 # for DexGuard only
 #-keepresourcexmlelements manifest/application/meta-data@value=GlideModule
```

Answer (score 1):

add this rule to your ProGuard configuration:

```
-keep,includedescriptorclasses class android.support.customtabs.** { *; }
```

Answer (score 0):

This warning is because you miss the reference to android support jar for your proguard process.

Try to add the `android-support-v4.jar` back to your `libraryjars` parameter. E.g.

```
 -dontwarn android.support.**
 -keep class android.support.**
```

Comment: I tried that but it didnt work. If i add it, it gives another error about implementation of inner classes.

Comment: what is your `gradle.build` file?